# wp7 application bar without navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

My problem is that the application bar is not displayed on a page if I don't use the navigationservice to navigate to that page. My code is : frame.content = page, but I need an application bar. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments to [Derek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715450/wp7-application-bar-without-navigation/4715732#4715732). can't you have the second page be a static empty XAML file with just some sort of container, a [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) for instance. Then the user generated content could be placed into that instead of a dynamically generated page.

That way, you can just navigate to the page and populate the content, instead of messing with frame's content property directly.

Comment: I agree. Messing with the frame's Content property is not going to get you to any place helpful. I'd still like to understand the whole problem better, though :)

Comment: Me too, I'm curious how this framework @Vic is creating makes life easier for a developer than just throwing together a page yourself in XAML and VS / Blend. I might want to buy it if it really does :-)

Comment: Well, it's a multiplatform framework, WP7 is only one platform, the functions are given, a virtual machine interprets the bytecode on-the-fly and makes the user-generated code work. But I take your advice and make this work via ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

When your page is loaded, what is the value of the ApplicationBar.IsVisible property?

UPDATE: So, I would imagine that the problem is to do with updating the Content property of the PhoneApplicationFrame, rather than navigating to it using the NavigationService. Presumably, under the hood, it's doing whatever is necessary to show the application bar.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer a bit. Why do you need to update the Content property directly, instead of using the NavigationService?

Comment: Is there a page visible before you update the Content property, and does it have a visible application bar?

Comment: It seems to me that only the Applicationbar of the current source of NavigationService can be displayed or hidden. At first I navigate to this page, but after that I set the content of the frame to a second page, then navigate to a third page. When I set the content of the frame to the first page again, the navigationservice.currentsource contains the third page. So the answer for your modified question is yes. I cannot use navigationservice, because my second page is generated dynamically, cannot be stored in a .xaml.

Comment: Based on the information you've given so far I can't pretend to understand what you're doing in your application, but I'm pretty sure you could do whatever dynamic content generation you're doing in a page of it's own and navigate to it using the NavigationService instead. Clearly you're current approach is not working well, and I don't think you'll find a workaround. Feel free to provide more details about your application scenario so we can give a more informed solution to your problem.

Comment: The problem basically is that when I use navigationservice for a page, then load a second page by directly setting the content of frame, and then navigating back to the first page, an error is raised: the program cannot navigate to the same page (because navigationservice is at the first page already). I can handle this by setting a dummy query value (page.xaml?dummy=...) which is incremented every time I navigate to the page, but I must navigate to the first page and set the second page quite often, and every navigation opens a new page...

Comment: My second page is always a generated page (I have no influence on the content), because this is a programming framework. So the user adds controls to the page, then I must show it on the phone. Only my first (and third) page can be declared in .xaml.